# Coordinate axis - Why the name "axis"?

Tags: mathematics, terminology

In "natural life" "axis" is often used in terms of an axis of rotation. But in the mathematical sense, it's more used like a ruler. One could say an axis in **"natural life" sense has something to do with rotation around the axis** and **in math, it's more like a translation (physical sense) in direction of the axis** (position on the axis).

In German it's even more difficult to distinguigh this meanings as "axle" and "axis" are both "Achse" in german.

I suspect that [René Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes) deliberately chose the name "axis" for coordinate axis?

Comment: I'm quite sure that Descartes does **not** call "axis" the (coordinate) *axis*... simply because he did not use them.

Comment: Accoding to [Tripod](http://jeff560.tripod.com/a.html) : "**Axis** occurs in English in the phrase "the Axis or Altitude of the Cone" in 1571 in [A Geometricall Practise named Pantometria](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasures-thomas-digges-pantometria) by [Thomas Digges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Digges) (1546?-1595).

Comment: positions on the x axis are measured relative the the y axis (and vice-versa),, and they are symmetrical  - rotation.

Comment: Latin axis, English axle, German Achse are Indo-European cognates, and all have the same basic meaning, “point of rotation”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the use in analytic geometry seems to be from [conics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Eccentricity.2C_focus_and_directrix).

Accoding to [Tripod](http://jeff560.tripod.com/a.html) :

> **Axis** occurs in English in the phrase "the Axis or Altitude of the Cone" in 1571 in [A Geometricall Practise named Pantometria](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasures-thomas-digges-pantometria) by [Leonard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Digges_(scientist)) (c.1515 – c.1559)and [Thomas Digges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Digges) (1546?-1595).

As you can see into the first textbook on analytic geometry : Jan de Witt’s [Elementa Curvarum Linearum Liber Secundus](https://books.google.it/books?id=6W1h-sHLGIkC&pg=PA123) (1659), page 123, the latin term "axis" is always referred to conics.